# Desabilitar segundo click no NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo, ao qual contem um `menu drawer`, porém, estou com um problema de `multitoque`, ou seja, quando o usuário seleciona um item, e rapidamente seleciona novamente, ele mantém o `drawer aberto`.

Eu gostaria, de que quando o usuário selecionasse um item, o `drawer` se feche, e ignore o segundo click.

o evento que trato hoje é assim

```
exp_list_fragments.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                if (groupPosition == 3 && childPosition > 0) {
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 1:
                            logoutApplication(false);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            DialogSendEmail d = new DialogSendEmail(Activity_Main.this);
                            d.show();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            rt.questionExitSystem();
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    Child_Fragments child_fragment = group_fragments.get(groupPosition).getFragments().get(childPosition);
                    controller.setActionBarTitle(child_fragment.getTitle(), child_fragment.getIcone());
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_drawer_content,
                            child_fragment.getFragment()).commit();
                }
                setFragmentSelection(groupPosition, childPosition);
                layout_drawer.closeDrawer(layout_drawer_drawer);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Tente no final do método **onChildClick** mudar `return false;` para `return true;`. Isso faz com que o SO não trate mais este click capturado em nenhum método seguinte da hierarquia de listeners...assim como seu método já "tratou" o evento, vc não quer mais tratamentos futuros...